# Stationary density of $\{X_t\}$ as a solution of integral equation

Tags: time-series, markov-process, autoregressive, integral

For the model, $X_t = \alpha X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, we find the integral equation related to stationary distribution in the following way:

Let $X_{t-1}\thicksim f$ and $X_t|X_{t-1}=x \thicksim q(y|x)$. Then the joint density of $(X_{t-1}, X_t)$ will be $q(y|x)f(x)$. Thus, clearly, the density $f$ is stationary iff it satisfies the integral equation: $$f(y) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^ {\infty}q(y|x)f(x)dx.$$

**My question:** When I consider the model $X_t = \alpha_{t-1} X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, I think, I can not proceed in the same manner because $\alpha_{t-1}$ is now a function of $t$ and the transition matrix of the Markov chain changes (the probabilities to reach to $X_t$ from $X_{t-1}$) as the $t$ varies. How can one find the integral equation related to the stationary density in this case?

Note: $\{\alpha_t\}$ can be chosen so that the stationary density of $\{X_t\}$ exists.